# Why are Lists causing problems

Tags: python, list

So I am working on a certain code to modify a text file. When I use this function individually, it works perfectly

```
TextRotation.rotTextC("cv.txt")
```

But when I use it in batch as a list like this

```
def files_LTXT(pathF):
    return glob.glob(pathF + "*" + ".txt")

for i in range (len(listFileTXT)):
    TextRotation.rotTextC(listFileTXT[i])
```

IT gives the following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\openCV\TextRotation.py", line 
    9, in rotLineC
    0
    valueObj = int(lineStr[c1])
    0.472917 0.713281 0.845833 0.376563
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Function rotLineC is as follows:

```
def rotLineC(lineStr, c1):
if len(lineStr) > 2:
    valueObj = int(lineStr[c1])
    print(valueObj)
    valueXC = float(lineStr[(c1+2):(c1+10)])
    valueYC = float(lineStr[(c1+11):(c1+19)])
    valueW = float(lineStr[(c1+20):(c1+28)])
    valueH = float(lineStr[(c1+29):(c1+37)])

    # print(valueXC)
    # print(valueYC)
    # print(valueW)
    # print(valueH)

    nValueXC = round(1 - valueYC, 6)
    nValueYC = round(valueXC, 6)
    nValueW = round(valueH, 6)
    nValueH = round(valueW, 6)

    rotString = str(int(valueObj)) + " " + str(nValueXC) + " " + \
                str(nValueYC) + " " + str(nValueW) + " " + str(nValueH)

    print(str(nValueXC) + " " + str(nValueYC) + " " + str(nValueW) + " " + str(nValueH))
    print(rotString)
    return rotString
```

This function works fine!

```
for i in range (len(listFileJPG)):
      ImageRotation.rotImage(listFileJPG[i])
```

Comment: Is `listFileTXT` a string?

Comment: No it's a list of files python list

Answer (score 0):

Mind to include the `/` to the end of the path! (I am assuming a UNIX environment here)

If the path is 'dev/my_pat', for example, your function will fail. The path must end with a `/`. You can it to your function:

```
...
if pathF[-1] != '/':
    return glob.glob(pathF + "/*.txt")
...
```

Also, do not iterate using indices, use the pythonic way!

```
for file in listFileTXT(my_path):
    TextRotation.rotTextC(file)
```

Comment: Nope still same error. Windows 10! I've edited the question so you can see other function that is of opencv works perfectly fine in rotating images.